# Receiving message from SQS: received message is different from sent message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

I am working with a SQS queue where I send an element using Python boto.
When I try to receive it from Java, I get something else, not the same body.

This is my Java:

```java
CreateQueueRequest createQueueRequest = new CreateQueueRequest().withQueueName("random_queue");
String queueUrl = sqsClient.createQueue(createQueueRequest).getQueueUrl();
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueUrl).withWaitTimeSeconds(20);
            List<Message> messages = sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
            System.out.println(messages.toString());
            for (Message message : messages) {
                String element = message.getBody();

                System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + element + "'");
}
```

output: `[x] Received 'ZGY1YzNiODYtNTM4Ny00NzVmLThkMGEtMDc4MzkxM2M2YWY5'`

Python code:

```py
my_queue = conn.create_queue('random_queue', 900)
m = my_queue.read()
body= m.get_body()

print body
```

output : `df5c3b86-5387-475f-8d0a-0783913c6af9` (This is the actual message I sent in the queue)

Why is my Java returning a different message to Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java code is returning in base 64 . Decode it to get original message.